# Atom: Unable to install linter-ui-default package

Tags: atom-editor, linter

I wanted to use `linter` with the latest atom editor, so I tried the below command on my newly installed editor:

```
C:\Users\rmishra>apm install linter-ui-default
Installing linter-ui-default to C:\Users\rmishra\.atom\packages failed
```

And here is the error while installing the package:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i\package.json'
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i No description
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i No repository field.
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i No README data
npm WARN apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\rmishra\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.28.0-beta1\\resou
rces\\app\\apm\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rmishra\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-1.
28.0-beta1\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalco
nfig" "C:\\Users\\rmishra\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\rmish
ra\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\rmishra\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-11869-
10100-far1m8.8vs517zaor\\package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=2.0.1" "--a
rch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7l
yqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\linter-ui-default
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData
\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\linter-ui
-default' -> 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7l
yqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\.linter-ui-default.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta1\r
esources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta
1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta1\resources\a
pp\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:267:18
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData
\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\linter-ui
-default' -> 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7l
yqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\.linter-ui-default.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppDat
a\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\linter-u
i-default' -> 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7
lyqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\.linter-ui-default.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta1\r
esources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta
1\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.28.0-beta1\resources\a
pp\apm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:267:18
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData
\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7lyqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\linter-ui
-default' -> 'C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7l
yqkv.gak66wp14i\node_modules\.linter-ui-default.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-11869-10100-7ly
qkv.gak66wp14i\npm-debug.log
```

I have also tried `apm clean` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/steelbrain/linter-ui-default/issues/369), but of no use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Close all processes and clean your Temp (`C:\Users\rmishra\AppData\Local\Temp`) directory shown in the image and try again

Comment: I cleaned the temp and installed a fresh copy, but it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to search for package.json in specified location. Couple of things you can try.

1. Make sure you have write access on given directory.
2. try to create package.json manually using [npm init command](http://weaintplastic.github.io/web-development-field-guide/Development/Frontend_Development/Setting_up_your_project/Setup_Dependency_Managers/Node_Package_Manager/Initialize_NPM_on_a_new_project.html)
3. Manually create directory and paste package.json on that directory and try to run command again.

Hope this will help.